# Datetime error in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Can some one help me to fix this error ..Not able declare a **datetime**

[image]

Comment: Isn't it DateTime with capital T?

Comment: I tried to change Datetime to DateTime But its automatically changed to Datetime ?

Comment: did you try System.DateTime?

Comment: Have you created your own custom class in your solution somewhere called "Datetime"?

Comment: I think you haven't imported Systems assembly like, Imports System at the top of your file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `Datetime` to `DateTime`.

And you are getting `DateTime` converted as `Datetime` coz your project's name is **Datetime**, so your immediate class name or namespace would also be Datetime. Change your class name or else use Date or else use fully qualified name for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare `DateTime` with its full `NameSpace` as `System.DateTime` . This is because your application `NameSpace` is also `Datetime` and is the default. VB is not case sensitive so when you declare Datetime it refers to your application `NameSpace`.

Answer (score 0):

The type is DateTime with capital 'T' and not Datetime refer [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your time .. the prob is my proj name is Datetime that's am not able to declare DateTime in my project..

Answer (score 0):

The .NET type name is `DateTime` (not the capital 'T', VB is case-sensitive about type names).

VB.NET has a type alias called `Date` (which is not case sensitive).

However `Datetime` is not valid, so just correct it to `DateTime`

Comment: I tried to change Datetime to DateTime But its automatically changed to Datetime ?.. do u think is there any issue with system or vs2010